# Set image source of one control to image source of another control in wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, triggers

I have 5 Image controls in WPF for thumbnail view and 1 Image control for enlarged view.

I want to set EnlargedImageControl source property to source of one of the 5 Thumbnail Image's source on Hover

```
<Image Source="{Binding DataContext.PassportSizeImage, ElementName=Root}"/>
<Image Source="{Binding DataContext.PassportImage, ElementName=Root}"/>
<Image Source="{Binding DataContext.VisaImage, ElementName=Root}"/>
<Image Source="{Binding DataContext.SSNImage, ElementName=Root}"/>
<Image Source="{Binding DataContext.BarCodeImage, ElementName=Root}">
```

When mouse is taken on any of the above 5 images, I need to set source property of that image to a source property of ZoomImage below.

```
--Set ZoomImage source equal to image last hovered above.
<Image Name="ZoomImage" Source="{Binding DataContext.BarCodeImage, ElementName=Root}">
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough english to explain detail.
 I just hope you can understand what I say. Anyway, should you use only binding of xaml? I think their is easy way, if you use event handler.
 You can use event handler such as

```
private void Image_MouseEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // TODO:
  // Set Image.
}

private void Image_MouseLeave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // TODO:
  // Reset image.
}
```

But it's may be thread unsafe, so I suggest **IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged** event.
 It's **DependencyPropertyChangedEvent**, and you can use it like as follow,

```
<!-- *.xaml file -->
<UserControl x:Class=... ... ... ...
             ... ... ... ... ... ...
             x:Name="FaverName"
             Width="..." Height="...">
  <!-- 
    ...
  -->
  <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel_Images">
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.PassportSizeImage}"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.PassportImage}"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.VisaImage}"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.SSNImage}"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.BarCodeImage}">
  </StackPanel>
  <!-- 
    ...
  -->
  <!-- This control is target. -->
  <Image Source="{Binding ElementName="FaverName", Path="ZoomedImageSource}"/>
</UserControl>
```

And then, code behind.

```
// .cs file
// DependencyProperty for binding.
static public readonly DependencyProperty ZoomedImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomedImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(YourUserControl));
public ImageSource ZoomedImageSource
{
  get { return GetValue(ZoomedImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
  set { SetValue(ZoomedImageSourceProperty, value); }
}

public YourUserControl()
{
  // ...

  // Chain new event.
  foreach(Image item in StackPanel_Images.Children)
  {
    item.IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged += (s, e)=>
    {
      if((bool)e.NewValue)
        ZoomedImageSource = (s as Image).Source;
    }
  }
}
// ...
```